# I keep getting the error message: "Conflicting types for 'sqrt' "

Tags: c, function, math, protocols, sqrt

I just started an intro to computer programming class, I only know 2 weeks worth of programming. 
I keep getting the "conflicting types for 'sqrt' " so I made a prototype and I'm still getting the message. I've tried everything.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float distance(float a, float b, float c, float d);


int main()
{
   int a,b,c,d,D;
   printf("Please enter the first x coordinate. x1= ");
   scanf("%f",&a);
   printf("Please enter the first x coordinate. y1= ");
   scanf("%f",&b);
   printf("Please enter the first x coordinate. x2= ");
   scanf("%f",&c);
   printf("Please enter the first x coordinate. y2= ");
   scanf("%f",&d);

   D = distance(a,b,c,d);
   printf("Distance = %.4f",D);

   return 0; 
}

float distance(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2)
{ 
  float d, D, x, y, X, Y;
  x = x1 - x2;
  y = y1 - y2;
  X = x*x;
  Y = y*y;
  d = X + Y;
  float sqrt (float d);
}
```

Comment: You are redeclaring sqrt() I think. Remove the float statement in front of sqrt()

Answer (score 1):

This is a function declaration

```
float sqrt (float d);
```

if you want to return the result of the function call you need

```
return sqrt(d);
```

also, the conflicting type error is due to the fact that the `sqrt` function prototype is

```
double sqrt(double x);
```

there is a `float` equivalent

```
float sqrtf(float x);
```

so perhaps your function should return

```
return sqrtf(d);
```

---

**Note**: I don't see any benefit in splitting this calculation so much you could just

```
return sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
```

Comment: Simplification: `return hypotf(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);`